# TFSBuild 2010 Custom Activity : IBuildDetail.LastGoodBuildUri == null?

Tags: tfsbuild

I am attempting to use a custom workflow activity to auto-increment build numbers based on the previously-successful build. This method worked with the MSBuild-based "workflow" but I cannot seem to get TFS to report the correct "last good build" for the currently-running build definition.

What I'm doing is pretty simple:

```
IBuildDetail build = context.GetExtension<IBuildDetail>();
IBuildDetail last = build.BuildServer.GetBuild(build.BuildDefinition.LastGoodBuildUri);
```

I have run a successful build already, which my code activity forced to have a build number of BuildName_1.0.0.0. But when I try to get this build and extract the version number, `GetBuild` complains that `LastGoodBuildUri` is null.

The custom build template I'm using sets both `CompilationStatus` and `TestStatus` to `BuildPhaseStatus.Succeeded` at the end, so TFS should be able to tell that this is a good build. What else am I missing?

Comment: Hey Michael, did you set the build's FinishTime? And what is the reason of this build?

Comment: These are all manually triggered builds -- we don't do CI or gated checkins. And no, I didn't explicitly set the FinishTime, though I thought I had picked up everything the default template was doing. Since we don't have nor plan to spend $$ on VS2010 Test or VS2010 Lab editions, I stripped all of the related things out. Is there something important in there I need to do?

Comment: I think I misread your question a little bit, I'll answer them below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running this code inside a custom activity, you need to make sure:

1. The build (`IBuildDetail`) is completed and saved to the server prior to the schedule of this custom activity.
2. The `IBuildDetail` instance or the `IBuildDefinition` instance (`build.BuildDefinition`) is refreshed, to get the latest changes from the server.

You can check if your build is completed by using `IBuildDetail.IsFinished`. If it is finished, refresh the BuildDefinition object using `IBuildDefinition.Refresh()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The custom action I'm running this code in happens very early in the build -- it's replacing the default build number logic that occurs in the Set Drop Location sequence. At that point, I'm trying to read the Uri for the _previous_ build for this build definition, which ought to be available from the very beginning. In TFS2008, what I needed was stored in the $(LastGoodBuildNumber) variable, I'm just trying to get the same information from the TFS2010 object model.

Comment: I see, Michael. If you have access to the database, can you take a look at the tbl_BuildDefinition to see if your build definition has the correct last good build information? Also check the last build of that build definition in the tbl_Build table to see what value it has for Compilation Status, Test Status, Build Reason and Finish Time. Let me know if I can contact you directly to investigate this issue.

Comment: Aha. Yes, this was my problem. I was setting the compilation and test status with a basic Assigment activity when I need to be using the SetBuildProperties activity -- apparently my status updates were not being saved.